# Why are there different versions of Bing Translate on Excel 2016/2019?

Tags: microsoft-excel, translation, bing

I using Bing Translate built inside Excel. I am using Excel 2019 at the moment but I think this problem happens in other versions too.

In some computers, the interface looks like this:
[image: Single-cell with Insert button]

In this version, you can only translate one cell at a time. However once done you can insert that translation result to the active cell.

In some other computers, the interface is like this:
[image: Multiple cell without Insert button]

This version allows you to select multiple cells and translate them at the same time. However, after that you cannot insert those translation back to the active cells (no insert button).

Comment: Specific version numbers would be helpful

Comment: Office 2016 MIS version? Office 2019 Click to Run version?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Even though both Excel were 2019, one computer had 2019 Office license and the other had 2016 license. So upon checking the Version number in File - Info, it says Excel 2016! So the first Bing loaded according to the license and not the real software installed.
After putting in the right license for 2019, the second Bing started to show up.